# CSS3 Transition stutters when executing .load() and transitions at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transition

I was testing out this [awesome new modal plugin](http://labs.voronianski.com/jquery.avgrund.js/) and was running into an issue. In the template: area I create a div with an id of popupModal as shown below:

```
$('#ContactModalLink').avgrund({
        height: 340,
        width: 400,
        showClose: false,
        showCloseText: '',
        enableStackAnimation: true,
        onBlurContainer: 'body',
        template: '<div id="popupModal"></div>'
});
```

At first I thought I would be able to use .load anywhere, but since the div does not exist until after the element is clicked I did this to load my url into the popup:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#ContactModalLink').click(function(){
        $('#popupModal').load('/ModalForm.aspx');
    });
});
```

This let's me load the url into my div, even when setTimeout is at 0. However, the CSS transitions have an unbearable hiccup right in the middle. I feel like I have tried everything to no avail.

Thank you so much!

Comment: CSS transitions (even gif animations for that matter) tend to hiccup when DOM manipulation is underway. I had to go through this too and feel your pain.

Comment: How did you end up getting it to work? If I changed all of my transitions to jQuery animations I presume it would work, but that would be a pain. Is there any way to stop the .load until the transition has completed?

Comment: It would still, unfortunately, not work. The problem stems from the fact that DOM manipulation and transitions, animations etc. all require browser redraw. My solution was to start the transition after the DOM manipulation was complete, but this may not work for you.

Comment: Thanks much. I'll see if I can't rewrite it to load that div on page load and then do transitions. I would've tried forever so thank you very much!